# Does a typical home router support classless IP address?

Tags: networking, router, internet, ip, subnet

All typical home routers I know of allow us to set a custom subnet mask, and because of this, I am really curious about whether they support the use of classless addressing scheme, meaning that in the LAN side, we can use whatever IP address range we like (regardless of the classes) and assign arbitrary subnet mask length and when we access the internet, the router will still work as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classful addressing is dead.  Classes are superseded by the subnet mask.  If it lets you specify a subnet mask, it's not classful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Since years ago home routers allows classless addressing.

Whenever you see that the router configuration interface has a field to put the subnet mask, it means that the router supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever address space you like on the local side of a home router, with the caveat that if it conflicts with a routable address space on the Internet, you *will not* be able to reach that space because your router will attempt to find it locally.

This is the reason that you should use RFC 1918 address spaces (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, or 192.168.0.0/16) internally unless you have sufficient publicly-routable address space assigned to you by your ISP (which is becoming increasingly rare).  Even then, there are reasons to use RFC 1918 space unless you have a very clear idea of how to secure your local network.

Comment: This is very almost, but not quite right in 2 important points - You can't use whatever space you like on the local side of the router UNLESS YOU USE NAT [ and it will break routing to that network as you said ],  and you should not be relying on RFC1918 space to secure your local network - http://blog.webernetz.net/2013/05/21/why-nat-has-nothing-to-do-with-security/

Comment: Home routers typically default to NAT, but that is a useful clarification.

I agree that RFC1918 isn't a security method of its own, but if you are provided a routable range, it's generally safer to use the private ranges for most things if you don't know how to perform the basics to secure your network, leaving the routable addresses to the DMZ functionality. However, this circumstance has become exceptionally rare.